# How to adjust table data dynamically based on header using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when the data is fetched from the ajax call it has to be sorted out in the table , table headers are id , email , Name. The data has to be displayed from the table. In my case i have append function once the ajax returns the data the append function merge the data in the table. Since some of the data are not properly aligned due to the data(Some have lengthy email id,name etc..) . hence i wrote a function once the data is appended below function will adjust the data according to the header. But it is not working.So how to fix this

```
function positionTableHeaders(headerTableId,bodyTableId)
{
    var tdIndex ;
    var thIndex ;
    var tdElement ;
    var thElement ; 

    try
    {
    $("#"+bodyTableId+" tr:first td").each(function() {
        tdIndex = $(this).index();
        tdElement = $(this);
        tdElementWidth = $(this).width();
        $("#"+headerTableId+" th").each(function(){
            thElement = $(this);
            thIndex = thElement.index();

            if(tdIndex == thIndex)
                thElement.width(tdElement.width());
        });
    });
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log("Exception occurred while positioning history table headers => "+err.message);
    }
}
```